# Hierarchical GridView asp.net 3.5

Tags: listview

Any ideas on how I can acheive 'Hierarchical' gridview? What I want is Parent-child cascading (Multi level).
 I am using LINQ to XML to fetch data from an XML file and persist it in the C# object and dispaly the data in a ListView Control with all the different levels of hierarchy. (C# object is the data source for the Listview Control).
Thanks in advance.
M

Can somebody help me please..

My C# objects :

1) AutoElements Class :

```
 
public class AutoElements : CommonElements
    {
       public class results_dataset
         {
            public List claimsHistory { get; set; }
          }      
        public class Claims_history
        {
            public List claim { get; set; }
            public typesectionEnum type; // attribute 
        }

        public class Claim : ClaimType
        {
            public string first_payment_date { get; set; }
            public ClaimAssociationIndicatorEnum claim_association_indicator;
            public List vehicle; 
        }

    }
```

2) Common Elements Class :

```
 public  class CommonElements : CPRulesCommonElements 
  {
     public class ClaimType
        {
            public string  claim_date { get; set; }
            public int claim_Age_Years {get; set;}
            public int claim_Age_Months { get; set; }
            public List policy { get; set; }
            public List subject { get; set; }
            public List address { get; set; }
        }

 public class SubjectType  : BaseSubjectType
      {
        public int unit_number {get; set;}
        public IDREF id {get; set;}
        public string id { get; set; }

      }
    public class BaseSubjectType
    {
        public string birthdate { get; set; }
        public GenderEnum gender { get; set; }
        public string ssn { get; set; }
        public string deathdate { get; set; }
        public string quoteback { get; set; }
        public List address { get; set;}
        public TelephoneType telephone { get; set; }
        public List driversLicense { get; set; }
     }
 public class DriversLicenseType : CPdriversLicenseType 
    {
        public DriversLicenseClassificationEnum classification { get; set; }
        public LenientDateType issue_date { get; set; }
        public string issue_date { get; set; }
        public LenientDateType expiration_date { get; set; }
        public string expiration_date { get; set; }
        public FSIEnum fsi_state { get; set; }
        public FSIEnum fsi_number { get; set; }
        public FSIEnum fsi_classification { get; set; }
        public string license_type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

3) CPRulesCommonElements :

```
   public class CPRulesCommonElements : Enums

    {
       public class telephoneType
        {
            public TelephoneTypeEnum type { get; set; }
            public string country { get; set; }
            public string area { get; set; }
            public string exchange { get; set; }
            public string number {get; set;}
            public string extension {get; set;}
        }
        public class driversLicenseType
        {
            public List parameter { get; set; }
            public DriversLicenseHistoryEnum history { get; set; }
            public DriversLicenseTypeEnum type { get; set; }
            public string state { get; set; }
            public string number { get; set; }

        }
```

Comment: Can somebody please respond to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with a GridView, but it is possible with a ListView.

See http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/01/building_a_grouping_grid_with.html for a good example.